# How do I calculate x where a^x=b?

Tags: c#, .net, math

My program needs to calculate `x` in the formula `a^x = b`, where I know the values of `a` and `b`.

So for instance, if:

- a=3 and b=9, the answer would be 2.
- a=3 and b=27, the answer is 3.
- What if a=2 and b=5?

I could write my own iterative algorithm, but is there a built-in function, or some simple combination of built-in functions?

Comment: Sorry that should be 'x' in the formula a^x =b not 'n' of course!

Comment: By `^`, you mean exponentiation, not XOR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x = Math.Log(b, a);
```

Comment: @Jon: Tried to post several times, since the answer itself is too short ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: Can you see the exact TS somehow?

Comment: @Jon: move your mouse pointer over "answered 12 mins ago". The same works for rep points below nickname too.

Comment: @zerkms: Didn't know that one and never did it by chance either. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys. Knew it was something really easy. Unfortunately high school was a looong time ago! I give my vote to zerkms for the quickest mouse click :)

Answer (score 9):

What you want to calculate is the logarithm of `b` in base `a`. So

```
var x = Math.Log(b, a);
```